# Neo4j / What is a good practice to deactivate an object?

Tags: database-design, graph, neo4j, graph-databases

Let's suppose a user wants to sell his car.
Technically, the corresponding `Car` node is about to be created in the graph.

Now the user changes his mind and wants to keep his car, meaning to remove it from the selling zone.
So the `Car` node should be deleted, but not physically (like 99% of the applications).
Most applications dealing with RDBMS would put a flag `Activated` to `false` or `N`.

With Neo4j 2.X, I think of two solutions:

- Creating a `Cancellation` **node**, linked to the `Car` by the relationship `CANCELS`.     Thus following the principle of **Models facts as Node** of [Graph Databases book](http://graphdatabases.com).
- Adding a **label** `Activated` when the `Car` was initially created and just dropping it when the cancellation occurs.

This way, there would be two ways of retrieving **current cars to sell**:

- `MATCH (c:Car:Activated) RETURN c`
- `MATCH (c:Car) WHERE NOT (c)<-[:CANCELS]-() RETURN c`

Which way should I choose and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Neo4j 2.x I would change a label, mostly because:

- There is likely to be a lot of Cancellation items, that potentially can create a dense node, being heavy to traverse
- A Label is easy to back with an index, so you can filter more using that as you grow
- Since this just a marker, not a scalar value like a date or so, a Label makes perfect sense here, you don't need the freedom to potentially create more relationships from/to the Cancellation node - filtering and sorting is probably fine and works great with an index backing this label.

Comment: Thanks a lot Peter, let's go for the label ;)

Comment: And what if I want to let the user point out the reason of the cancellation. Should I merely create a node `CancelReason` linked to the car whose label `Activated` was dropped?

Comment: With 2.1.X, it seems that a heavy node could still efficiently be traversed thanks to a variant of the algorithm under the hood, couldn't it?

Comment: I would add a Cancel-reason property on the car if this is a free-form cancellation reason. If there are a small number of possibilities, I would do a label for them. `Cancelled_Defect` etc.

Comment: Great :) So if I well figure out, since the creation of labels feature in 2.X, the "models facts as nodes" may often be implemented by a Label rather than a node. => we could say "models some facts as Labels" :)? Am I right?